# Что должен знать программист о Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Какие знания программисту нужны о этой CMS?
В смысле, что нужно знать помимо того, как натянуть вёрстку и написать плагин?

Comment: наветное то, что с ним лучше не связываься.

Comment: Почему Вы так считаете?

Comment: Ну оочень расплывчатый вопрос. Загляните к примеру в [API][1].


  [1]: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs

Comment: >Почему Вы так считаете?

@NyaXA не обращайте внимания, это не всерьез

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потребуется знание кодекса WP, в котором описаны все возможные выводы постов, страниц, медиа-файлов и т.д. Так же можно посмотреть на сайте http://wp-kama.ru/

Comment: Если будут возникать вопросы-обращайся ;)